# Error when trying to send transactional email from template using sendGrid

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I'm trying to send a transactional email via node using sendGrid. Below is an example of my code.

```
        const subject = 'Email subject';
        const templateId = 'templateId';
        const sg = require('sendgrid')(secret);
        const request = sg.emptyRequest({
            method: 'POST',
            path: '/v3/mail/send',
            body: {
                "personalizations": [
                    {
                        "bcc": userEmails,
                        "substitutions": {
                            "-userName-": userDetails.name,
                            "-productPrice-": productDetails.price,
                            "-productUrl-": productDetails.url,
                            "-productPercentageDrop-": productDetails.percentageDrop,
                            "-productName-": productDetails.name,
                            "-productOriginalPrice-": productDetails.origPrice,
                            "-productDroppedPrice-": productDetails.dropPrice,
                            "-productImageUrl-": productDetails.imageUrl
                        },
                        "subject": subject.substring(0, 75)
                    }
                ],
                "from": {
                    "email": "myemail",
                    "name": "myname"
                },
                "content": [
                    {
                        "type": "text/html"
                    }
                ],
                "template_id": templateId
            }
        });

        sg.API(request, function (error, response) {
            if (error) {

                console.log('Error response received');
            }
            console.log(response.body.errors);
        });
```

But every time I run the code I get the following error message.

`400
 message: 'Bad Request', field: null, help: null`

Which isn't really that helpful when trying to find out why its erroring.

Body JSON being sent:

```
{
"host":"",
"method":"POST",
"path":"/v3/mail/send",
"headers":{

},
"body":{
    "personalizations":[
        {
            "bcc":[
                {
                    "email":"name1@hotmail.com",
                    "name":"name1"
                },
                {
                    "email":"name2@hotmail.com",
                    "name":"name2"
                }
            ],
            "substitutions":{
                "-productPrice-":189.5,
                "-productUrl-":"http://www.tesco.com/direct/humax-fvp-4000t500-m-smart-freeview-play-hd-digital-tv-recorder-with-wi-fi-500gb/483-1785.prd",
                "-productName-":"Tesco direct: Humax FVP-4000T/500 (M) Smart Freeview Play HD Digital TV Recorder with Wi-Fi - 500GB"
            },
            "subject":"Product Tesco direct: Humax FVP-4000T/500 (M) Smart Freeview Play HD Digita"
        }
    ],
    "from":{
        "email":"email@pricetracker.io",
        "name":"Pricetracker"
    },
    "content":[
        {
            "type":"text/html"
        }
    ],
    "template_id":"XXXXXX"
},
"queryParams":{

},
"test":false,
"port":""
```

}

Comment: Can you please post the raw JSON request body being sent? Does your template contain both a `subject` and `content` ?

Comment: @bwest added the JSON request

Comment: Try removing the content parameter entirely

Comment: Just tried and unfortunately that didn't make any difference.

Comment: Okay, and your template definitely has content specified in it?

Comment: I would also try adding a `value` to your text `content` part and see if that works, just to help pinpoint the error

Comment: @bwest I've just tried the other 2 suggestions and still getting the error message and in my template I'm referencing the following `-productPrice-` as above.

Comment: Oh... I just noticed you don't have a To field, only BCC. Gotta have a To.

Comment: @bwest I've just updated following your latest comments eg replace the 'bcc' to 'to' and still getting the same error.

Comment: Just to confirm, please post the contents of your template, and verify the template ID. If this doesn't work I ask that you please open a ticket with SendGrid support.

Comment: My other suggestion is to get the simplest possible use case working (one email, no subs, no replaceements), and then add each part until you can isolate where the problem is.

Comment: @bwest found the issue... it was this `"-productPrice-":189.5` it didn't like be passing through numbers, it has to be a string. Thanks for your help, I would give more points if I could.

Answer (score 1):

don't know if this could still be helpful for you, but I've had some similar issues when using substitutions with Sendgrid. I'm using the sendgrid-php library, but internally it sends the same format. What I found was that all substitution values should be converted to string. For instance your value for productPrice should be like this:

```
"-productPrice-": "189.5",
```

With quotes. In my case I had integers, and when I converted them to strings, all worked correctly.

Comment: Same for me as well. The error output was not saying anything. It was just giving `bad request 400`. Cascading the values to string just worked properly. The php api does not accept INT values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not passing string value to the template file then SendGrid will give you

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Request","field":null,"help":null}]}
```

Convert your all non-string value to string before sending to the template file.

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue, then I fix using this below syntax, change only you message format.

```
"value": "'.html_entity_decode((str_replace('"',"'",$message))).'"
```